# Odoo 9 - IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I added below model as `one2many` on `hr.holidays` model.

When I try to save the record its showing IO ERROR:

I gave chmod -R 777 to odoo root folder. But didn't work.

NOTE: It working fine on local machine, the problem only on sever.

***.py**

```py
class LeaveAttachments(models.Model):
_name = "leave.attachment"

leave_request_id = fields.Many2one('hr.holidays', 'Leave request')
name = fields.Char('Description')
file = fields.Binary('Attachments',compute='get_file',inverse='set_file')
file_name = fields.Char('File name')
note = fields.Char('Notes')

@api.one
def set_file(self):
    open(self.get_file_name(), 'w').write(self.file.decode('base64'))

@api.one
def get_file(self):
    file = False
    try:
        file = open(self.get_file_name(), 'r').read().encode('base64')

    except:
        pass
    self.file = file
```

How can i resolve this?

**EDIT:**

Output of `ls la /odoo/

[image]

Comment: That doesn't necessarily enough, you have to change the owner of you folder entirely also to be sure

Comment: If you don't know how ? put a result of  screenshoot of cmd : `ls -la`

Comment: @khelilimiliana, I updated my question with the output.

Comment: `chown -R :odoo odoo`

Comment: @khelilimiliana, I tried your solution but same error.

Comment: Where is the code of get_file_name and post the error message exactly

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify path that you are trying to open file from location. It seems path used different from your expectation.

OR

You can try with absolute path to check folder permission working or not.

Comment: You are open file. So check that file absolute path. To make sure, on that path, you have given correct permission.